# What Does "Local Computer Resources" Comprise in Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

In the Windows Task Scheduler, the interface allows me to use a specific user to run the task (`General > Security options`). Under the *Run whether user is logged on or not* option, the interface has a checkbox with the text: *Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources.*

I have been searching for the meaning of "local computer resources", but every site seems to assume the definition. I have an idea about what it means, but my experience with the Task Scheduler leads me to believe that "local computer resources" indicates fewer resources that I thought it did.

Which privileges do I have with the *Do not store password* option?

Answer (score 4):

My experience indicates that ADS authentication with a remote Domain Server exceeds "local computer resources", so you can't run a task as an ADS username without storing a password. You can of course create a local user on that machine who will be authenticated locally without Task Scheduler storing the password.

However, check out the discussion of "S4U" here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152.aspx

Maybe it's not actually the authentication, but the fact that our ADS users' homedirs are on network servers.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, local resources will be local drives in this case. And so task scheduler will not be able to access any network resource. And about storing password option, this [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152.aspx) article might help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152.aspx):

> If your task requires access to network resources, you cannot use S4U;
>   doing so will cause your task to fail. The only exception is the case
>   where constrained delegation was established between the computers
>   involved in the operation.

However, my scheduled task *is* able to open a web browser and connect to websites that require Active Directory authentication.

Comment: My scheduled task was _not_ able to access the network (a LAN webserver) with the password not stored. Are you sure you weren’t logged in when your scheduled task was triggered?