# Task Scheduler intermittent failure (Error Value: 2147943767)

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

In Windows 10, I have a Task in the Windows Task Scheduler that triggers at a certain time and also can run on demand. The Task comprises four Actions, each calling the same program with very similar options.

Though the first of the four Actions will occasionally succeed, the Task will always fail on the second action. The failure produces details similar to:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler" Guid="{GUID####-##...}" /> 
        <EventID>101</EventID> 
        <Version>0</Version> 
        <Level>2</Level> 
        <Task>101</Task> 
        <Opcode>101</Opcode> 
        <Keywords>0x8000000000000001</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="1900-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>54906</EventRecordID> 
        <Correlation /> 
        <Execution ProcessID="76" ThreadID="10964" /> 
        <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational</Channel> 
        <Computer>ryan-pc.bplogix.com</Computer> 
        <Security UserID="S-###" /> 
    </System>
    <EventData Name="TaskStartFailedEvent">
        <Data Name="TaskName">\Name-of-Task</Data>
        <Data Name="UserContext">DOMAIN\user</Data>
        <Data Name="ResultCode">2147943767</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

If the first Action fails, the Task reports:

> The operator or administrator has refused the request 0x800710E0

I use the "Run whether user is logged on or not" option, and I see results like these whether or not I have checked the "Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources." option (and again, [what does that option mean?](https://superuser.com/q/579856/45163)). The user [has "Log on as a batch job" rights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14259467/393280), and I can run the same command in a normal non-elevated command prompt window successfully every time.

What could cause this failure and if it fails sometimes, why would it succeed at all?

Comment: Have you considered configuring the task to run as the System user, instead?  From my perspective, that always seems to be the most reliable method for creating a Windows scheduled task but it may not be suitable for your specific scenario.

Comment: running as "System" solved my 2147943711 and 2147943767 issues

Comment: I have my reasons that I would like to run the task as a particular user, and running as System doesn't really answer the question I asked.